# How to echo node value with javascript (on load)?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have this code that loads php, when the page loads:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#time').load('https://www.mywebsite.com/trigger.php');
});</script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

and I have trigger.php:

```
<?php
$parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
$html_string = file_get_contents('https://mywebsite.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$values = array();
$row = $xpath->query('//*[@id="canvass-0-CanvassApplet"]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]');
foreach($row as $value) {
   print($value->nodeValue);

}

?>
```

but it doesn't load.

I know I need to echo in the .php first.
So I have tried to `echo $value;` instead of print, but still nothing.

When I type something simple like `<?php echo 'heyyy load me';>` then it does work.

How do I echo my php code?

Need help, thanks.

Comment: What is the output of the server?  Sharing the `status code` and `body` will make things easier for us to understand whats wrong.

Comment: It's doesn't output anything. Basically, I need to figure out how to echo my code first.  When I use print($value->nodeValue); in a single php, I can see my desired output. But script can't output print. Only already echoed values in trigger.php

Comment: nevermind, I found the same solution using a simple iframe.